# What is the app-win32.c file in Android NDK San Angeles sample for?

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk

I'm exploring OpenGL ES on Android for the first time, particularly the San Angeles sample provided by the NDK. One file that caught my attention was `app-win32.c`. It contained what seemed to be codes that setup a native window on Windows OS using Win32 APIs for running the San Angeles sample.

On the contrary, I have found almost nothing of running OpenGL ES directly on Windows without the use of emulators. Can someone please explain to me? I plan to start incorporating OpenGL ES into my existing NDK app. It would be a great of help if I can test the OpenGL ES codes directly on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL ES is a cross-platform library specification. You can write cross-platform apps with it, that work even in a browser, not only under Windows (see google native client for details). You can also write Linux or Mac OS X apps with OpenGL ES. The means of creating an OpenGL context and associating it with a window usually differ on different platforms, though. For this reason, you usually need to write platform-specific code to create the GL context, the other (OpenGL) code can then be more or less platform-agnostic.

EDIT:

`app-win32.c` creates an OpenGL ES context and associates it with a window it creates. It also implements a message loop for the window. Its purpose is to test the demo outside of the Android emulator.

Comment: Sorry, could you be more specific? I'm well aware of what OpenGL ES is for. I'm asking about the purpose of app-win32.c

Comment: If you look into the source, you'll see a `wndProc` and context generation code. The purpose of the file is to test the SanAngeles demo under Windows, without the help of the Android emulator.

Comment: Would you be able to show me how to get it running on Windows? Thanks.